# Can't resolve all parameters for ViewController: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular4-forms

I am working in a project, and using IONIC 3 and Angular 4. In between i need to create a component which is responsible for creating popover controller. I can transfer data from that component to the popover component very easily. But getting issue when trying to transfer data from popover component to that component and getting weird kind of error *Can't resolve all parameters for ViewController: (?, ?, ?)* .

**Error:**
[image]

```html
import { Component, OnInit, Host } from '@angular/core';
import { PageContainerComponent } from '../../component/pagecontainer/pagecontainer.component';
import { CommunicationService } from '../../service/communication-service/communication.service';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams ,ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'autorefresh-comp',
  template: `
    <ion-grid class="dropdown-setting">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-md-6>
        <ion-label class="label-text">Auto Refresh</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-4>
        <ion-toggle checked={{toggleVal}} [(ngModel)]="refreshalVal.toggleValSelected"></ion-toggle>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-md-12><hr></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-md-4>
        <ion-label class="label-text">Set Time</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-8>
      <ion-list >
        <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Select</ion-label>        
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="refreshalVal.seconds" (click)=onDismiss(refreshalVal) interface="popover">
          <ion-option value="{{enumVal[i]}}" *ngFor="let sec of enumVal; let i = index;" >{{enumVal[i]}} seconds</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
              </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <h1>{{refreshalVal.toggleValSelected}}</h1>
    <h1>{{refreshalVal.seconds}}</h1>
  
  <ion-grid>
    `
})

export class AutoRefreshComp {

  enumVal: any;
  toggleVal: any;
  refreshalVal:any={};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public viewController:ViewController) {
  }


  ionViewWillLoad() {
    this.enumVal = this.navParams.get("enumVal");
    console.log("enumVal received:: ", this.enumVal);
    this.toggleVal = this.navParams.get("toggleVal");
    this.refreshalVal.toggleValSelected= this.toggleVal;
    console.log("toggleVal received:: ", this.toggleVal);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PopoverPage');
  }

  onDismiss(data){

    console.log(this.viewController);
    this.viewController.onDidDismiss(data);
    }



}
```

```html
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler, IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { PageContainerComponent } from './component/pagecontainer/pagecontainer.component';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { DynamicComponentService } from './MW-Ionic/dynamicservice/dynamic.service';
import { AngularLayoutWidget } from './MW-Ionic/layout-widget/angular2-layout-widget';
import { MetawidgetComponent } from './MW-Ionic/metawidget/metawidget.component';
import { Angular2WidgetProcessor } from './MW-Ionic/widgetprocessor/angular2-widget-processor.component';
import { HttpService } from './service/http-service/http.service';
import { ShareModule } from './share.module';
import { FilterComponent } from './component/filter/filter.component';
import { TableComponent } from './component/table/table.component';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicationService } from './service/communication-service/communication.service';
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import {ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';


//Widget As Component
import { 
  InputBoxComponent,
  ComboBoxComponent,
  DateComponent,
  CheckboxComponent,
  RadioComponent,
  ToggleComponent,
  ButtonComponent,
  TitleComponent,
  LookupComponent,
  SignatureComponent,
  SignatureButtonComponent,
  ListComponent,
  TextAreaComponent,
  OutputComponent,
  RowComponet,
  AutoRefreshSetting,
  AutoRefreshComp
} from './MW-Ionic/widget-component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageContainerComponent,  
    InputBoxComponent,
    ComboBoxComponent,
    DateComponent,
    FilterComponent,
    TableComponent,
    CheckboxComponent,
    ToggleComponent,
    RadioComponent,
    ButtonComponent,
    TitleComponent,
    LookupComponent,
    SignatureComponent,
    SignatureButtonComponent,
    ListComponent,
    TextAreaComponent,
    OutputComponent,
    RowComponet,
    AutoRefreshSetting,
    AutoRefreshComp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ShareModule,
    HttpModule,
    SignaturePadModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(PageContainerComponent, {
      menuType: 'push',
      platforms: {
        ios: {
          menuType: 'overlay',
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  bootstrap: [ IonicApp ],
  entryComponents: [
    PageContainerComponent,
    FilterComponent,
    TableComponent,
    SignatureComponent,
    ListComponent,
    AutoRefreshComp
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    DynamicComponentService,
    PageContainerComponent,
    HttpService,
    CommunicationService,
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler, 
      useClass: IonicErrorHandler
    },
    ViewController
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Component creating popover**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Host } from '@angular/core';
import { PageContainerComponent } from '../../component/pagecontainer/pagecontainer.component';
import { CommunicationService } from '../../service/communication-service/communication.service';
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular/components/popover/popover-controller';
import {AutoRefreshComp} from './auto-refresh.component';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'autorefresh',
    template: `
           <div class="btn-group btn-group-filter-col-right js-btn-group-setting">
            <button ion-button outline (click)="openRefreshPageSetter($event)"> <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon> <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown" class="icon-arrow"></ion-icon></button>
           </div>
    `
})

export class AutoRefreshSetting implements OnInit{

  public attributes : any;
  public enumVal : any;

  constructor(public popoverController: PopoverController,
    @Host() private pageContainer: PageContainerComponent,
    private commService: CommunicationService) {
  }

  openRefreshPageSetter(any){
    console.log("calling openRefreshPage() method.....");
    let popover = this.popoverController.create(AutoRefreshComp,{enumVal:this.attributes.enum,toggleVal:this.attributes.autorefreshToggle});
    popover.present({
      ev: any
    });

    popover.onDidDismiss(data =>{
      console.log("data got from popover:: ",data);
    })


  }

  ngOnInit(){
   console.log("Attributes ===> "+JSON.stringify(this.attributes));
  }



}
```

Comment: Hey I'm doing the same.Can you Please console.log(data) the data onDismiss() function and tell me what you're getting over there??

Comment: Hi @AneriVala thanks for your response.Actually this is not able to reach onDismiss() method  itself, before itself i am getting this error.May be  i think while declaring into provider i am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was a three step process

- Do not add ViewController as provider
- Add the necessary parameters in the Modal constructor

`js
constructor(public viewController: ViewController,
    public params: NavParams,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public platform: Platform) {
    this.itemList = params.get('itemList');
    this.editItem = params.get('editItem');
  }`

- Make sure you are declaring the ModalPage both in declarations and entryComponents.